# ionic infinit list reload cached page/view

Tags: list, caching, ionic-framework

I have an ionic list page with template cached set to true, each item is clickable and the only way to avoid a reload is to cache the page. However, i need to to reload the list from another menu option but it appears that my controller isn't triggering. I've tried setting up difference services using &ionicHistory to clearcache and clearhistory, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my heads a few times, the following solution worked! by forcing the reload of my list controller with the following:

$state.go("app.tabs.your_controller", {}, {reload: true});

NOTE: that $stateParams wouldn't take effect since the page wasn't loading, instead the "reload: true" works like a charm. I continue to use $state.go("app.tabs.your_controller") on other pages which don't require a page reload.